# where is the module level string.upper function in Python 3?

Tags: python-2to3

How do I get this code to work in 3?

**Please note that I am not asking about `"foo".upper()` at the string instance level.**

```
import string
try:
    print("string module, upper function:")
    print(string.upper)
    foo = string.upper("Foo")
    print("foo:%s" % (foo))
except (Exception,) as e:
    raise
```

output on 2:

```
string module, upper function:
<function upper at 0x10baad848>
foo:FOO
```

output on 3:

```
string module, upper function:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dummytst223.py", line 70, in <module>
    test_string_upper()
  File "dummytst223.py", line 63, in test_string_upper
    print(string.upper)
AttributeError: module 'string' has no attribute 'upper'
```

`help(string)` wasn't very helpful either.  Far as I can tell, the only function left is `string.capwords`.

**Note: a bit hacky, but here's a my short-term workaround.**

```
import string

try:
    _ = string.upper
except (AttributeError,) as e:
    def upper(s):
        return s.upper()
    string.upper = upper
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#deprecated-string-functions: "You should consider these functions as deprecated, although they will not be removed until Python 3."  Use the string instance methods.

Comment: txs.  if you put it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All of the `string` module-level functions you describe were removed in Python 3.  The [Python 2 `string` module documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#deprecated-string-functions) contains this note:

> You should consider these functions as deprecated, although they will not be removed until Python 3.

If you have `string.upper(foo)` in Python 2, you need to convert that to `foo.upper()` in Python 3.